# How to deploy smart contracts to any arbitrary available address like it was done through a regular transaction on Optimism?

Tags: contract-deployment, addresses, layer-2

Well, I’m not talking about the mainnet but an ᴇᴠᴍ compatible ʟ2 still using an Ethereum smart‑contract for storing its state : Optimistic Ethereum.

A recent contract creation on Optimism seems to prove it is possible to create a contract at an arbitrary address, or a system address since system contracts start by `0x42` on Optimism. But the problem is that by looking at block explorer data, [the transaction looks like a plain normal `CREATE` transaction without any contract interaction nor code change in their fork of Geth](https://optimistic.etherscan.io/tx/0x1f3b8418e8784d1a79158c9af5b5e5f80ef79a7a8f9da8248ffbd5b58b293850). Yet, `0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000014` definitely looks like not to be a randomly generated address.

So, how can I deploy a contract to `0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000015` for example ? Or if it was a privileged operation, how it was implemented as `0x53A6eecC2dD4795Fcc68940ddc6B4d53Bd88Bd9E` is [a normal mainnet address with its Optimism funds having been bridged from Ethereum](https://etherscan.io/address/0x53a6eecc2dd4795fcc68940ddc6b4d53bd88bd9e) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason how Optimism was able to reserve both the [`0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000014`](https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000014) and [`0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000042`](https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000042) contract addresses, even though they deployed to those smart contract addresses after genesis.

If we check the creation transactions for the above smart contracts, the deployer accounts would be `0x53a6eecc2dd4795fcc68940ddc6b4d53bd88bd9e` and `0xcde47c1a5e2d60b9ff262b0a3b6d486048575ad9` in order. I went ahead and tried to see if I could reverse-engineer the process and compute the `CREATE1` address of the smart contracts from the deployer accounts and using an nonce of `0` for both accounts using the following Solidity script:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

contract ComputeCREATE1 {
    function contractAddressFrom(address deployer, uint256 nonce) public pure returns (address) {
        if(nonce == 0x00)     return address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd6), bytes1(0x94), deployer, bytes1(0x80))))));
        if(nonce <= 0x7f)     return address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd6), bytes1(0x94), deployer, bytes1(uint8(nonce)))))));
        if(nonce <= 0xff)     return address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd7), bytes1(0x94), deployer, bytes1(0x81), uint8(nonce))))));
        if(nonce <= 0xffff)   return address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd8), bytes1(0x94), deployer, bytes1(0x82), uint16(nonce))))));
        if(nonce <= 0xffffff) return address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd9), bytes1(0x94), deployer, bytes1(0x83), uint24(nonce))))));
        return address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xda), bytes1(0x94), deployer, bytes1(0x84), uint32(nonce))))));
    }
}
```

The computed `CREATE1` contract addresses were `0xa923A72d8FCa361a8Db421c807B8980354B8698f` and `0x3c0BEaDFeAdCa4D7d3bc2567968e7b3b57486082` in order. That triggered my curiosity, because it meant that the first deployed smart contract addresses were being computed differently for said deployer accounts.

I went ahead and started searching Optimism's geth implementation to see what was going on, and here's what I found out:

1. Both the [deployer accounts](https://github.com/henry-hz/optimism/blob/2d3216cdef477a8df8622fc3d19273afafd8d7cb/l2geth/rollup/rcfg/system_address.go#L51) and the [smart contract addresses above](https://github.com/henry-hz/optimism/blob/2d3216cdef477a8df8622fc3d19273afafd8d7cb/l2geth/rollup/rcfg/system_address.go#L9) were hardcoded in `l2geth/rollup/rcfg/system_address.go`.
2. Optimism had it's own implementation for `CREATE1` in `l2geth/core/vm/evm`, where it checked the caller's account and nonce to [see if it was a system-reserved deployer account](https://github.com/ethereum-optimism/optimism/blob/2b3b09be268fb9bd1112706370497d9d8ff7883e/l2geth/core/vm/evm.go#L426). If it was, then the `CREATE1` contract address should be one of the above hard-coded addresses, and not computed via the default `CREATE1` process as in the Solidity script above.

Comment: But seriously… Getting a specific address like `0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000014` is has much as possible as bruteforcing arbitrary Ethereum public key… You also won’t get so many `0` with bruteforcing.

Comment: I’m thinking what happened is Optimism specific and the question is about finding what…

Comment: @user2284570 I found out the correct answer, and I've updated it above. I hope you find my explanation sufficient :)

Answer (score 0):

use `create2` opcode. From [deploying-with-create2](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.8/deploying-with-create2)

> The whole idea behind this opcode is to make the resulting address
> independent of future events. Regardless of what may happen on the
> blockchain, it will always be possible to deploy the contract at the
> precomputed address.
>
> New addresses are a function of:
>
> - 0xFF, a constant that prevents collisions with CREATE
> - The sender’s own address
> - A salt (an arbitrary value provided by the sender)
> - The to-be-deployed contract’s bytecode

```
new_address = hash(0xFF, sender, salt, bytecode)
```

> CREATE2 guarantees that if sender ever deploys bytecode using CREATE2
> and the provided salt, it will be stored in new_address.
>
> Because bytecode is included in this computation other agents can rely
> on the fact that, if a contract is ever deployed to new_address, it
> will be one they know about. This is the key concept behind
> counterfactual deployments.

this is an example of how Uniswap uses in [UniswapV2Factory.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol)

```
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB)
        external
        returns (address pair)
    {
        require(tokenA != tokenB, "UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES");
        (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB
            ? (tokenA, tokenB)
            : (tokenB, tokenA);
        require(token0 != address(0), "UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS");
        require(
            getPair[token0][token1] == address(0),
            "UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS"
        );         
        bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
         
        // CREATE2 opcode gives us the ability predict the address where a contract will be deployed, without ever having to do so. This opens up lots of possibilities to improve  
      
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
        assembly {
            pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1);
        getPair[token0][token1] = pair;
        getPair[token1][token0] = pair; // populate mapping in the reverse direction
        allPairs.push(pair);
        emit PairCreated(token0, token1, pair, allPairs.length);
    }
```

Comment: Wrong answer ! the question isn’t to have a fixed address but arbitrary addresses like `0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000014`… Remember it’s Otpimism, not the true Ethereum and **hence the question is how a regular transaction managed to have a contract deployed on `0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000014`** ?

Answer (score -1):

`0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000014` is a system address reserved for future pre-deploys.

See: https://twitter.com/scottfits/status/1531798505198481408/photo/1

And contracts that start by `0x42` are considered pre-deploys that are marked as created by Genesis, meaning they are available from the blockchain's beginning. Hence, I don't think you can deploy a contract to the address `0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000015`. The address `0x53A6eecC2dD4795Fcc68940ddc6B4d53Bd88Bd9E` is a wallet address of a L1 account.

See: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/wallet/mainnet/0x53a6eecc2dd4795fcc68940ddc6b4d53bd88bd9e

Comment: Yet, `0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000014` was created by a regular transaction and not from Genesis state. I was asking how this was implemented for a transaction to deploy a contract at that address, even if this was allowed before.

Comment: `0x53A6eecC2dD4795Fcc68940ddc6B4d53Bd88Bd9E` [is the address L2 used for deploying funded by it s L1 counterpart](https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0x53A6eecC2dD4795Fcc68940ddc6B4d53Bd88Bd9E) and is not only an L1 address.